# Can I move an app's data to another phone?

Tags: storage, data-transfer

I have a game running on an old phone and since the game doesn't save any data in a cloud and neither does google play, I wanted to transfer the data from my old phone's storage to my current one, or just save it on an external drive for when I uninstall the game. Where do I find the data folder, and where do I have to put it on the drive/other phone?

(both are Android just to clarify)

The link to the game is https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ironhorsegames.idlewasteland

Thanks in advance.

Comment: some manufacturers provide app to migrate phone like samsung smart switch, huawei phone clone, etc...